# How to define `reqId` value in parent block

Tags: javascript

`There are 2 blocks parent and child... 'reqId' is being used in child block but it is undefined as it is declared in parent-block. Also 'reqId' is a fallback.

```
//Parent-block
func Paymentprocessing = async (body) = {

    const reqId = uuid();  //defined here "reqId"
    
    try {
        const Channels =
            payload?.payment_process?.entity?.data?.channel ||
           payload.payment_process.entity.data.channel;
        switch (Channels) {
            case "phonePe":
                await phonePeHandle(body);
                break;

}
return {status: 200};
}catch (e) {}
}

//Child-block
async function phonePeHandle(body){
if(body.event === constants.paymentMode.phonePe) {

        let requestId = payload.payment_process.entity.data.reqId || reqId;  //used here "reqId"
    
        await phonePeService.callback(requestId, body);
        return {status: 200};
    }

}` `
```

How to get the value  of 'reqId' defined in the parent , which is being used in child-block.`

Comment: Pass it into the `phonePeHandle` function when you call it, perhaps?

Comment: which func @Andy

Comment: I tried doing this `async function phonePeHandle(body,reqId)` but its still undefined. @Andy

Comment: Are you also passing it into the function `await phonePeHandle(body, reqId)`?

Comment: Thanks @Andy. Also is there a way that we can get it defined in the parent here `const reqId = uuid();` . Just for curiosity I am asking.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. It _is_ defined in the parent function.

Comment: @Andy I mean to say can we define its value in parent function in line `const reqId = uuid();`

Comment: That's where the value of `reqId` _is_ being defined. Sorry, I'm still not clear what you're asking.